# Cell stacking on each other in Jupyter dashboard view

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dashboard

I'm new to the Jupyter notebook. When I am moving to the dashboard grid layout, all off my cells are stack upon each other without any option of moving them. In addition, I can't go back to regular notebook view without reentering the notebook.

I've tried to play with the settings without success. Then I switched all my code to just 2 simple headings and it is still happening. Couldn't find any answers on the web.

Anyone has an idea how to solve it?

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1560 - check this one out - seems to be a bug

Comment: Great, Thanks you!