# Cells unreadable/un-editable in Jupyter dashboards extension

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dashboard

I am having an issue in the jupyter dashboards extension:

https://jupyter-dashboards-layout.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#

When I move to grid view, all cells get stacked on top of each other making it impossible to read or even edit. Additionally, it will not let me switch back to notebook view without exiting and reopening the notebook.

This question seems like it has been asked:

[Cell stacking on each other in Jupyter dashboard view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022942/cell-stacking-on-each-other-in-jupyter-dashboard-view)

but I don't think it's actually been answered. Has anybody else come across this issue?

Comment: As you found the matching question, did you see the GitHub issue mentioned in the comments? https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1560 --> there are some possible solutions described

Comment: I have looked at that thread. It’s not as much to do with this particular extension I am talking about as I think it was more of a general bug.